# Does caldav expose a property to identify whether an event is in a floating timezone?

Tags: caldav

Do caldav exposes property to identify whether event is in floating timezone or not?

Answer (score 1):

To tell if the event is in "floating timezone", check the DTSTART property. If the value is not UTC (i.e. not ending with "Z") and the property doesn't have a TZID parameter, its start is a floating time (see e.g. RFC5545 3.2.19, section "Description")